# Реализовать обновление TextBlock при изменении свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="250">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=P, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1">Изменить значение свойства</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            P = "1";
        }

        private string p;

        public string P
        {
            get { return p; }
            set { p = value; }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            P = "2";
        } 
    }
}
```

В программе выполняется связывание свойства P с свойством `TextBlock.Text`. При нажатии на кнопку меняется значение свойства на "2" но текст в `TextBlock` остается "1". Как можно реализовать обновление `TextBlock` при изменении свойства?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте DependencyProperty вместо вашего `public string P`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty <имя_проперти> = DependencyProperty.Register(
            <имя_свойства>,
            typeof(<тип_свойства>),
            typeof(<ваш_контрол>),
            new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(PropertyChanged));
```

Событие `PropertyChanged`:

```
private static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            <ваш_контрол> control = depObj as <ваш_контрол>;
            if (e.Property == <имя_свойства>)
            {
                control.<ваш_текстбокс>.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
                return;
            }
        }
```

И само свойство:

```
    public string <имя_свойства>
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(<имя_проперти>); }
        set { SetValue(<имя_проперти>, value); }
    }
```

В XAML разметке:

```
  <<ваш_нэймспейс>:<ваш_контрол> <имя_проперти>="{Binding <имя_свойства>}"/>
```

Comment: Это на каждую переменную, которую я хочу связать, писать столько кода? Легче обновлять текстбокс из кода напрямую.

Comment: по-вашему, это "много кода"?)

Comment: По сравнению с тем чтобы написать TextBlock.Text="2" при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: Ну так не надо писать руками. Есть сниппет. Попробуйте `propdp<Tab><Tab>`, вы будете удивлены. (Это если вы работаете в Visual Studio, конечно.)

Answer (score 4):

Что бы меньше писать сделай отдельный класс и реализуй интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged что-то типа:

```
public partial class Xxxxx : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _p;

        public string P
        {
            get { return _p; }
            set
            {
                if (_p != value)
                {
                    _p = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("P");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

И будет счастье!